# branch is ahead of 'origin/master' of authoritative repository

Tags: git

I have several remote GIT repositories and one of them is authoritative which used by many people. All changes should be committed to the authoritative repository. Unfortunately, I have committed some changes to one of the remote repositories which is not authoritative and the latter one became inconsistent:

(from a remote repo)

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
```

Is there any safe method to make the authoritative server consistent with others?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You could push your change to `origin`: `git push origin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge your branch back into origin/master and push it back up to the remote repo you consider authoritative.

Comment: The original push which caused such problem was done from my local computer. And I lost that local repo. What should I do in this case? Thank you

Comment: Just SSH\Login into the non-authoritative remote repo, do the merge there, and then push the merge to your authoritative repo.

Answer (score 1):

> The original push which caused such problem was done from my local computer. And I lost that local repo.

By cloning the non-authoritative repo, you get back your commits.

Then you can `git remote add authoritative ssh:/url/to/authoritative-repo` and simply push back to the authoritative one.

```
git push authoritative master
```